# Using CriteriaDelete for delete operations

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I'm using JPA Criteria API, and I want to remove "Actions" that have "Loop" is equal to the passed param, so I did as following:

```
public void removeByLoopId(final Long id) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaDelete<Action> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(Action.class);
    Root<Action> root = delete.from(Action.class);
    delete.where(cb.equal(root.get(Action.actor).get(Actor_.step).get(Step_.loop).get(Loop_.id), id));
    getEntityManager().createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
}
```

But I'm getting this exception :

```
ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

This is the generated SQL query:

```
delete
    from
        IKURUSAKI.Action cross
    join
        IKURUSAKI.Actor cross
    join
        IKURUSAKI.Step cross
    join
        IKURUSAKI.Loop 
    where
        id=10738;
```

Comment: Have you tried to create your own Joins from Action to Loop? And then use the equals on the join?

Comment: @kaba713 I don't think that's possible since UPDATE/DELETE criteria queries cannot define joins

Comment: Not directly but you could create a subquery that does just that for you.